# Remove incomplete ways from OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, osmium

I'm trying to extract all data OSM within a GeoJSON polygon using `osmium extract`. I want the output to include only nodes and ways *completely* contained within the polygon. I tried using the `--strategy simple`, however this still includes ways that have at least one node within the polygon.

I checked quickly using the Overpass API and it has the same behaviour.

Is there a way to do this using `osmium` or `osmosis`? Or do I need to write my own program?